# GRANT REFERENCE on all user defined types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The original problem is: a user, who has the permission to create/alter view granted is getting this message when trying to perform either operation:

> Cannot find the type 'nvarchar', because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permission.

Through some internet digging I found it may be caused because he does not have `GRANT REFERENCE` permission on types. However,

```
select * from sys.types order by name
```

Returns over 2000 records, and `GRANT REFERENCE` command accepts a single type as parameter. How can I grant this user the reference permission for **ALL** types?

Comment: I think this is a XY problem. Can you post the alter he is trying to execute on the view? There might be a typo that's making SQL Server think that `NVARCHAR` is a type instead of a common data type.

Comment: I cannot post the query, however I can execute it just fine - but I do have elevated permissions on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do something like this, just use dynamic SQL to generate the command.

```
SELECT t.name, 
       'GRANT REFERENCES ON TYPE::' 
       + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) 
       + '.' 
       + t.name 
       + ' TO public;' AS command_to_run
FROM   sys.types AS t;
```

Comment: This script is handy for UDTs but I'd like to see a repro where it's required for the built in `nvarchar` system type called out in the question.

Comment: @DanGuzman I would too, but apparently we're not getting one here ¯\_(ツ)_/¯